# Mongo, find through list of ids

Tags: mongodb

I have a process that returns a list of String MongoDB ids,

```
[512d5793abb900bf3e20d012, 512d5793abb900bf3e20d011]
```

And I want to fire a single query to Mongo and get the matching documents back in the same order as the list.

What is the shell notation to do this?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

After converting the strings into ObjectIds, you can use the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#_S_in) operator to get the docs in the list. There isn't any query notation to get the docs back in the order of your list, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order) for some ways to handle that.

```js
var ids = ['512d5793abb900bf3e20d012', '512d5793abb900bf3e20d011'];
var obj_ids = ids.map(function(id) { return ObjectId(id); });
db.test.find({_id: {$in: obj_ids}});
```

Comment: This is working perfectly but i have an other query where i want only one record for the list of ids what should i do for that ?

Comment: how can i get ids in an array from this : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("611b96a6699005a8f561fe52")
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("611b96a2699005a8f561fe51")
        }

Comment: This works pretty well, but there is one issue with that. If you pass [ObjectId("id1", "id3", "id2")] and if in the database the order of records is "id1", "id2", "id3", it will return them into the latter order. What if I want it to return them into the exactly the same order as the ids array ?

Answer (score 12):

This works fine for me in Robo 3T. No need to create any object and just use the list of ids.

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({'_id':{$in:['aa37ba96']}})
```

Comment: I'm using pymongo in Python 3.8 and had to put quotes around `$in` in order to make it pass the linter and actually run.

Comment: Is it scalable for very long list? For example: suppose I have a list of 50-100 ids and then I try to use `$in` to find all the matching documents. 
Or should I find another way?

Answer (score 0):

If your final purpose is to get the document with the order by your pre-get ids list, you can just convert the query result into mapping(id as key, doc as value) , and then traverse the ids list to get the doc.

Comment: I'm after the query that will return the results...?  Code example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

// categoryId comma separated "5c875c27d131b755d7abed86,5c875b0ad131b755d7abed81" in request

```
var ids= req.body.categoryId.split(','); 

db.test.find({ categoryId: { $in: ids } });
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. The question clearly shows an **array** and not a string. If you had something else to add on a **different** note, you could have [asked a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and posted your own response. Adding *unrelated* answers to existing questions is not necessary.