# What is a right way to get an array of objects from mongodb database initially having and an array of ids of objects from this collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is a problem. I get an array of Ids from client to find the full objects that contain in my database.Ultimately, after some aggregation/mapReduce( Anyway I can't really understand how to make it by any of these means) I have to get an array of full objects with all the rest fields. How to do it? Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Are you using mongoose or just vanilla mongo?

Comment: I use vanilla mongo

Comment: I think the answer your looking for is here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102532/mongo-find-through-list-of-ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102532/mongo-find-through-list-of-ids)