# How can I find multiple records of collection by mongo objectID

Tags: mongodb

> I am trying this query but its return only one record.

```
db.getCollection('lists').find({_id:ObjectId("5b51c7cf307331187c5429bd"),_id:ObjectId("5b507c322fa5767930f0a09f")})
```

> I also tried this but it returns nothing.

```
db.getCollection('lists').find({_id:ObjectId("5b51c7cf307331187c5429bd")},{_id:ObjectId("5b507c322fa5767930f0a09f")})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo, find through list of ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102532/mongo-find-through-list-of-ids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to find multiple records based on criteria.

#### $in:

```
db.getCollection('lists').find({_id: {"$in" : [ObjectId("5b51c7cf307331187c5429bd"), ObjectId("5b51c7cf307331187c5429bd")]}})
```

#### $or:

```
db.getCollection('lists').find({"$or" : [{ _id : ObjectId("5b51c7cf307331187c5429bd")}, { _id: ObjectId("5b51c7cf307331187c5429bd")}]})
```

Answer (score 1):

for the multiple you should use $in operator of mongodb you can take the reference from [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) dos