# How to fetch data from MongoDB database as per the insertion order?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, nosql

**Problem:** I am trying to fetch data from the `MongoDB` database as per the defined in an Array of ObjectId's. While fetching the data I have noticed that the data isn't ordered as per the defined ObjectId in the Array field.

```
module_id: [
  ObjectId('60f65202cfq57631f324061b'),
  ObjectId('60f66df8cfx57631f324061e'),
  ObjectId('60f66bedcfv57631f324061d'),
  ObjectId('610262e58eu2031d264e934b'),
  ObjectId('611a143bf66m223dd5338641'),
  ObjectId('6119efdf4770b836e1ceaf24')
]
```

**Desired Output:** I wanted the fetched result should be as per the array ids and I am passing the same order that is defined above but getting some random order result. Don't want to be by default sort.

To fetch the result using `.find({ _id: { $in: module_id }}).toArray(function (err, result) {console.log(result)})`

Does anybody have any idea where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Mongo, find through list of ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102532/mongo-find-through-list-of-ids)

you should loop through array

im try this and work fine in mongo shell

```
let ids=["6116b8175d761433233e1719","6116b8175d761433233e171a"]
 let objIds=ids.map((id)=>ObjectId(id))
 db.users.find({_id:{$in:objIds}})
```