# Node.js/ - MongoDB async/await weird behaviour?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await

Here, productIds has ID of all ordered items in an array like ["1294382", "2913892"]

So I'm trying to get all the items with those ID's from MongoDB's database. I'm mapping through each of them, and store them in orderedItems array. So that i can access price (or any property) of the item in database.

```
productRouter.post("/", async (req, res) => {
 
  const productIds = req.body.orderedItems.map((item) => item.id); 

  let orderedItems = [];

  productIds.map(async (productId) => {
    const d = await Product.findById(productId);
    orderedItems.push(d);
  });

  const unusedVariable = await Product.findById("61...da1"); //If i delete that line (or only await), orderedItems returns empty array. 

  console.log(orderedItems);
  
});
```

Now, expected output is:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("614632cc8aa9513567dfbca4"),
    name: 'ürün1',
    desc: 'ürün1 açıklama',
    price: 50,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("614632cc8aa9513567dfbca2"),
    name: 'kartal kupa',
    desc: 'kartal resimli kupa',
    price: 50,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

And I get that output, but only if I have the unusedVariable line with await. If i remove that line, or remove "await" from there, the output i get is: [] . So an empty array instead of filled with objects.

Why ? And how do i solve that (just leave unusuedVariable there?) ? How bad is this code ?

Comment: 1. don't use `map` when you mean `forEach` (it's confusing) 2. a forEach loop with await in the callback doesn't run in sequence and the code doesn't wait for the promises to finish. Use `const orderedItems = await Promise.all(productIds.map(productId => Product.findById(productId)));`

Comment: You should instead try making an array of findById operations and pass that array to Promise.all() and await that.

Comment: you are pushing in a callback, sure you made callback asynchronous but there is nothing awaiting the callback

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a concurrency issue. ​There is nothing unusual, you are not waiting for promises at `(1)` to end. The only reason your code is working is that MongoDB in your case uses a single connection and hence `(2)` is queued and completed only after `(1)` (all of them) are completed (it is a lucky coincidence of yours).

```
productRouter.post("/", async (req, res) => {
 ​const productIds = req.body.orderedItems.map((item) => item.id);
 ​let orderedItems = [];

 ​productIds.map(async (productId) => { // (1)
   ​const d = await Product.findById(productId);
   ​orderedItems.push(d);
 ​});

 ​const unusedVariable = await Product.findById("61...da1"); // (2)
 ​console.log(orderedItems);
});
```

As mentioned all-around nor `map` nor `forEach` supports promises (and they probably will never, due to backward compatibility) hence you should either use `Promise.all` which may give you some concurrence, or use plain `for` which is compatible with `async/await` syntax.

```
productRouter.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const productIds = req.body.orderedItems.map((item) => item.id);
  let orderedItems = [];

  for (const productId: productIds) {
    orderedItems.push(await Product.findById(productId));
  }
  
  console.log(orderedItems);
});
```

Or

```
productRouter.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const productIds = req.body.orderedItems.map((item) => item.id);
  
  const orderedItems = await Promise.all(
    productIds.map(productId => Product.findById(productId))
  );
  
  console.log(orderedItems);
});
```

#### Offtopic

As mentioned in the comments you should consider using `$in` operator, which will drastically reduce the number of queries against your DB:

```
productRouter.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const productIds = req.body.orderedItems.map((item) => item.id);
  const orderedItems = Product.find({_id: {$in: productIds}});
  console.log(orderedItems);
});
```

[More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102532/mongo-find-through-list-of-ids)

Comment: Thanks. That answers everything. So, when i use await in a callback function, code doesn't wait it to complete the task. Therefore returns empty orderedItems. So  I just use Promise.all in such cases. Also the code you provided worked.

Comment: Not exactly, when you use `await` you wait for a promise to end. But when you use __`async`__ you just declare a function that will return a Promise. (In your case `productIds.map(async ...` returns you an array of promises, but no one is waiting for them)

Comment: The link mentioned above will explain you better this process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Alright i will study that. Also about the Offtopic part, this may help someone: The code you provided doesn't work as expected, but this does (need to make them into ObjectId): 
  `const objIds = productIds.map((id) => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id));
  const orderedItems = await Product.find({ _id: { $in: objIds }, });` I'll use that one then since its more optimized